# file path is $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../tax_docs/' where should the folder "tax_docs" resides

Tags: php, file

The file path given is  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../tax_docs/'`   where should the folder "tax_docs" lies or is it same as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tax_docs/'`  .I am getting confused because of `'/../'`

What does this actually means ? Thank you.

Comment: Where should "tax_docs" reside? - The bin is the best bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`../` means to go up one level.

Give the following structure

> Home
>   --public_ftp/
>   --public_html/

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would most likely give you `Home/public_html`, so the folder `tax_docs` in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../tax_docs/'` should be placed in the Home directory giving you:

> Home
>   --public_ftp/
>   --public_html/
>   --tax_docs/